# Right sidebar overlaps content page with browser resize

Tags: css, resize, sidebar, screen-resolution

I need help in fixing my right sidebar in Wordpress so that it doesn't move around when seen in different resolution sizes on the screen?

**CSS for the right sidebar**

```
#socialsidebar { 
   float: right; 
   position: relative; 
   overflow: hidden; 
   margin-right: 200px; 
   margin-top: 200px; 
   height: auto; 
   width: 194px; 
}
```

**CSS for the container/page**

```
body { 
   min-width: 960px; 
}
.container_12 { 
   background: #fdfdfd; 
   margin-left: auto; 
   margin-right: auto; 
   width: 960px; 
}
```

Comment: Whats the resolution u tried. You gave a min-width :960px. So if you got below that, you will be having a problem

Comment: I coded it on my laptop with a screen resolution (1920 x 1200) but when I tested it on my desktop comp (1024 x 768) the right sidebar shifted over on top of the content page.

Comment: 960 + 194 is more than 1024 that's for sure... Maybe you should consider a percentage width? Can we see a live example of this?

Comment: @ceecamp in the fiddle you should put the resulting HTML and not the php code. Use browsers `View Source` to accomplish that.

Comment: don't give static width and right and top to your elements, set your container width to auto, and give percentage width to the right bar. also give a percentage right to it and percentage top: that way it will adjust accordingly to the screen resolution. other wise jquery/javascript is the word

Comment: @xpy, You can totally tell I'm new to this. Thank you and sorry about that.

Comment: @Manish I tried what you said, but it didn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about `position` property of CSS.

there are few thumb rules that you have to take care of.

1. avoid unnecessary horizontal scroll.
2. try not to give static height, cause you always have infinite height at your disposal. use `height:auto` for your bigger containers.
3. give static dimensions to such containers which you know can be accommodated on most of the resolutions.
4. avoid inline css - try to define generic css as much as possible.
5. decide the possible resolution range of your app usage. and then begin writing CSS.
6. and most importantly, always cross verify your CSS(as you write it) on IE(biggest challenge).

most of the time, best way to go about it is that it should be simple and easily modifiable.

see you need to look at the entire screen as a co-ordinate system whose origin is at top-left corner and Y-Axis downwards.

[this](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101) is one of the best articles on CSS-Position property. Go through it. It will help you in understanding how left,right,top,bottom work.

now, I've made a super simple sample, covering your needs. i.e. right navigation and it stays stable in any resolution.

## [Sample-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/3YJGq/)

what you should notice in this sample is, extensive usage of percentage for width, height, top, left. and position attribute.

you can modify it accordingly. or take a reference from it. one more thing, you don't need to do `position:absolute`, I am doing it cause, i wanted to provide dimension to the container through its top, left,right bottom attribute, you can do it through percentage and `position:relative`.